# ping: option requires an argument -- 'c' and 'usage: ping'

Tags: bash, shell-script, ping

Trying to run the below code, in order to display the the ip address, the number of packets received and transmitted.

```
#!/bin/bash

interface=$1
ip=$2
packet=$3

if [[ $1 == "-h" ]]
then
    echo "Perform ping command and get an automated result"
    echo "Perform like   ./ping_lan.sh Interface IP Packet "
    echo "Example: ./ping_lan.sh eno1 192.168.7.4 10"
    exit
fi

ping -I $interface -q $ip -c $3 >> ping_summary.txt

transmit=$(grep -o '[0-9]\+ packets transmitted' ping_summary.txt | grep -o '[0-9]\+')

receive=$(grep -o ', [0-9]\+ received' ping_summary.txt | grep -o '[0-9]\+')

packet_loss=$(grep -o ', [0-9]\+% packet loss' ping_summary.txt | grep -o '[0-9]\+')
cat ping_summary.txt >> summary.txt
rm ping_summary.txt

if [[ $transmit -ne $packet ]]
then
    echo -n "FAIL: transmit package is: "
    echo -n $transmit
    echo -n " expected: "
    echo $packet
    exit 1
 fi

 if [[ $receive -ne $packet ]]
 then
    echo -n "FAIL: receive package is: "
    echo -n $receive
    echo -n " expected: "
    echo $packet
    exit 1
 fi


 if [[ $packet_loss -ne 0 ]]
 then
    echo -n "FAIL: transmit package is: "
    echo -n $packet_loss
    echo -n "expected: "
    echo "0"
    exit 1
 fi

 exit 0
```

I am getting the error of `argument requires an argument`. I tried to replace `-c` with `--c` and also the 'usage ping'

What does 'usage ping', mean and why does it show ?

- What is this error mean?
- Why am I getting this error?
- How should I avoid this error ?

After using `bash -x script_name`, the output I got is:

```
+ interface=
+ ip=
+ packet=
+ [[ '' == \-\h ]]
+ ping -I -q -c 5
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV64] [-c count] [-i interval]         [-I interface]
[-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
[-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
[-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...] destination
Usage: ping -6 [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
[-l preload] [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option]
[-N nodeinfo_option] [-p pattern] [-Q tclass] [-s packetsize]
[-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option] [-w deadline]
[-W timeout] destination
++ grep -o '[0-9]\+ packets transmitted' ping_summary.txt
++ grep -o '[0-9]\+'
+ transmit=
++ grep -o ', [0-9]\+ received' ping_summary.txt
++ grep -o '[0-9]\+'
+ receive=
++ grep -o ', [0-9]\+% packet loss' ping_summary.txt
++ grep -o '[0-9]\+'
+ packet_loss=
+ cat ping_summary.txt
do_ping_lan.sh: line 22: summary.txt: Permission denied
+ rm ping_summary.txt
+ [[ '' -ne '' ]]
+ [[ '' -ne '' ]]
+ [[ '' -ne 0 ]]
+ exit 0
```

The command I use to call the script is:

```
    sudo ./script_name interface ip packet 
    sudo ./do_ping_lan.sh wlan0 192.168.0.1 5
```

Comment: `$packet` is probably empty, it's complaining about not being told how many packets to send.

Comment: interface=$1
ip=$2
packet=$3

if [[ "$1" == "-h" ]]
then
        echo "Perform ping command and get an automated result"
        echo "Perform like   ./ping_lan.sh Interface IP Packet "
        echo "Example: ./ping_lan.sh eno1 192.168.7.4 10"
        exit
fi

ping -I $interface -q $ip -c $packet >> ping_summary.txt

Comment: So above is the code where packet has been assigned $3

Comment: Please edit your question to include that, instead of replying in the comments.

Comment: Have edited the question!

Comment: ping utility, iputils-s20161105, the ping version, is it right ?. I used the command ping - V. I am new to bash and shell scripting and learning so @GAD3R

Comment: When entered 'ping -help' on terminal, I am able to see '-c' option in the usage list. @GAD3R

Comment: Run your script with `bash -x your_script` to see yourself what happens.

Comment: So I updated the output/result of bash -x your_script in the question @U.Windl

Comment: Hello Sir @roaima, I have edited the code and the result of bash -x your_script

Comment: Did you see that `-I` lacks the argument? ;-) You might also want to try a `if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then ... fi` to detect missing parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the script correctly. Look at the output:

```
+ ping -I -q -c 5
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV64] [-c count] [-i interval]         [-I interface]
```

You can clearly see that there are no values for any of the parameters, so `ping` gives you a usage message.

Later on,

```
+ cat ping_summary.txt
do_ping_lan.sh: line 22: summary.txt: Permission denied
```

You cannot write to `summary.txt` in the current directory. You need to write either to a temporary file (see answers on StackExchange relating to `mktemp`) or to some other file that is writable.

Comment: So Sir, when I call the script, I use the following command, "sudo ./do_pin_lan.sh wlan0 192.168.0.1 5" where interface is 'wlan0', ip is '192.168.0.1' and packet is '5'

Comment: Can I change the permission of summary.txt file toi writable?@roaima

Comment: @ShirkeMalvika it's your system so you could change the permission of `summary.txt` if it already exists

Comment: You need to update the question to show us how you call the program. _We cannot guess_.

Comment: I update in the question, Sir! I changed the permission for summary.txt file but still I am getting the same error.